# How do I avoid Error: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in Yii?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, cleardb

I keep getting this error incessantly. How do I avoid it with Yii? I saw some questions about Yii 1 but they use options that aren't in the documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

> Error: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away

The query is normally very simple.

> The SQL being executed was: SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `ad_group_keyword`

I'm using MySQL (from ClearDB) and I don't have access to the server configurations.

I added these attributes to the `db` but they did not help.

```
'attributes' => [
  PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, // ClearDB connection limit is 90s
  PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 90,
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'select 1',
]
```

Comment: That might not be a problem of Yii, but rather your server. It sounds like the server blocked the attemt to connect to it.

Comment: It works most of the time. But 1-2% failure rate is too high.

Comment: how about a little timer event you call every 60 seconds that says `select 7;`  !  it is a timeout issue with settings

Comment: Ok but how do I do that in Yii2? I didn't see an option in the docs for a timer callback. I seem to remember that option in Hibernate.

Comment: Adding this to the `db` seems to have mitigated it, but not eliminated it: `'attributes' => [
      PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false // ClearDB connection limit is 90s
    ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this by *migrating away from MySQL on ClearDB*. I wasn't the only person with this problem. https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2015/dedicated-vs-shared-databases-a-mysql-has-gone-way-fix/

I migrated from MySQL to Heroku Postgres. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16732524/148844